# Create a broken form with http.Client

Tags: forms, go, testing, http.client

How to create a 'broken' form for testing purposes with `http.Client` that will trigger a response error on `ParseForm()` in a handler function?

I have the following code:

```golang
func (app *App) signupUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil { // how to trigger this if statement?
        sendStatus(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "error parsing form")
        return
    }
...
```

Then during testing I'm using `http.Client` to test this controller:

```golang
resp, err = client.PostForm(ts.URL+"/user/signup", url.Values{
            "email":      {testEmail},
            "password":   {goodPassword},
)
if err != nil { 
  t.Error(err) // I never get here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `client.PostForm` will do a proper job of populating the post form, so you have to populate it manually.

Then if you dig into the call stack of `r.ParseForm()`, you'll eventually arrive to the error producers (barring reading issues, etc.):

`"net/url".QueryUnescape` which "*returns an error if any % is not followed by two hexadecimal digits.*"

So, for example:

```
    r := &http.Request{
        // ensures it reads the body
        Method: "POST", 
        // string with bad url encoding '%3z'
        Body: io.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("foo%3z1%26bar%3D2")),
        // ensures it parses the body as post form
        Header: map[string][]string{
            "Content-Type": []string{
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
        },
    }
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err == nil {
        panic("no err")
    }
    // err -> invalid URL escape "%3z"
```

Answer (score 0):

To tag onto blackgreen's answer, you can also simply pass in `nil` as the body to trigger an error. In the source code for `ParseForm()`, any POST request calls into `parsePostForm()`, which has a validation for the form body at the beginning of the function.

```
request, _ = http.NewRequest("POST", path, nil)
```